# Calculation lat/long- points for a pentagon around center

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude

I'm looking for a way to retrieve five points that would make a pentagon around a given center and a given distance.

Something like this:

```
getPentagonPoints = (latlng, distance) => {
  var pentagonLatLng = [];
  //magic calculations goes here
  return pentagonLatLng;
}
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990504/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-the-vertices-of-a-pentagon-centered-at-the-origin

Comment: @nem035 I don't think that's directly applicable, since it's putting the figure on a plane, not a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
function getPentagonPoints(latlng, distance) {
  var pentagonLatLng = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Pi * 2 is 360 degrees, in radians
    // We add 270 degrees (Pi * 1.5 radians) to start at the top
    const angle = Math.PI * 2 / 5 * i + Math.PI * 1.5; // in radians
    const lng = distance * Math.cos(angle) + latlng.lng;
    const lat = distance * Math.sin(angle) + latlng.lat;
    pentagonLatLng.push({lat, lng});
  }
  return pentagonLatLng;
}

// Just for the demo
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const latLng = { lat: 90, lng: 200 };
const points = getPentagonPoints(latLng, 50);

points.forEach((point, i) => {
  if (i === 0) { ctx.moveTo(point.lng, point.lat); }
  ctx.lineTo(point.lng, point.lat);
  if (i === points.length - 1) { ctx.lineTo(points[0].lng, points[0].lat); }
});

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="160"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think that's OK for a pentagon in the plane, but not on a sphere. (Since OP mentioned latitude and longitude it seems a sphere is implied.) It's probably OK for small pentagons not near the poles, but large pentagons and ones near the poles will be distorted. Maybe a way to go about it is to draw the figure on the equator and then rotate it to the desired latitude. Just guessing here.